# Separate Restful API in Yii2 Basic is failed when accessed by VirtualHost Apache2

Tags: php, yii2

Basically I follow this tutorial [Diggin](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating%2Ba%2BREST%2BAPI%2Bfor%2BYii2-basic-template) for create restfull api in Yii2 Basic.

So I create this directory schema,

```
+ api
   + config
     - api.php
     - params.php
   + modules
     + v1
         + controllers
           - UserController
     Module.php
+ config
   - web.php
   - params.php
```

**Here it is the UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;


class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['get'],
                    'view' => ['get'],
                    'create' => ['post'],
                    'update' => ['post'],
                    'delete' => ['delete'],
                    'deleteall' => ['post'],
                ],

            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**Here is the api.php**

```
<?php

$db = require(__DIR__ . '/../../config/db.php');
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'name' => 'RESTFull',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/..',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/api.log',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => ['v1/user']
                ],
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/api/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'app\api\modules\v1\Module' // here is our v1 modules
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

return $config;
```

**And this is the .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Now, the problem is**
I try this url to get data in postman: http://localhost/app_folder/api/v1/user , Thank God that I got the correct Json Data like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Administrator",
        "email": "email-me.com",
        "auth_key": "just-key",
        "password_hash": "just_password",
        "password_reset_token": null,
        "status": 10,
        "created_at": 1476816334,
        "updated_at": 1487220512
    },
]
```

But when I try to use Virtualhost like

```
<VirtualHost *:2200>
ServerName myserver.local   
DocumentRoot d:/wamp64/www/app_folder/api
<Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/app_folder/api/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

which is I am on windows machine, so I have to added a new name in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>notepad hosts

```
127.0.0.1   myserver.local
::1 myserver.local
```

then restart the Windows Machine.
Then try with this url : 'http://myserver.local:2200/api/v1/user' , postman said

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://myserver.local:2200/api/v1/user
```

What I missed, Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You are already pointing the virtual host to the api directoy. In case you have the index.php file in there your requests should be to

> http://myserver.local:2200/v1/user

not to

> http://myserver.local:2200/api/v1/user